# PL/SQL: Loop Through XML Column and Extract Value From Duplicate Elements

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have a SQL table that contains an XMLType column. I need to iterate through each row and extract values from the column.

The XML contain multiple children with the same will look like this:

```
<parent>
  <child>Test</child>
  <child>Test1</child>
  <child>Test2</child>
</parent>
```

My goal is to take the value from each child and append to a string. However, I am having issues extracting the value.

My current solution:

```
DECLARE
  sample VARCHAR(2000);
BEGIN
  FOR row IN (SELECT xml_column FROM table)
  LOOP
    FOR child in (SELECT EXTRACT('/parent/child') ...
    LOOP
      ....
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

My first issue is I cannot seem to get the individual values. I've used both EXTRACT and EXTRACTVALUE but the best I've gotten is 'TEST1TEST2...'.

Second, if I try using `row.XML_COLUMN` it complains that it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html#GUID-C4A32C58-33E5-4CF1-A1FE-039550D3ECFA) to
 iterate through the values like a set.

### Sample schema

```
--drop table table1;
create table table1 as
select xmltype('
    <parent>
        <child>Test</child>
        <child>Test1</child>
        <child>Test2</child>
    </parent>') xml_column
from dual;
```

### PL/SQL Loop

```
begin
    for children in
    (
        select child
        from table1
        cross join xmltable
        (
            '/parent/child'
            passing xml_column
            columns child varchar2(100) path '/'
        )
    ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(children.child);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

### DBMS_OUTPUT Results

```
Test
Test1
Test2
```

Comment: This worked, but could you explain the 'cross join' portion? I don't understand what this is doing.

Comment: @ghost013 The cross join is pretty strange.  It's really more like an OUTER APPLY, which is also a strange concept.  Each row in TABLE1 is passed into XMLTABLE and the results are multiplied, so that one XML value/row can be expanded to multiple relational rows.